# Get color from Xamarin.Forms.Color on android drawable XML

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is something like this possible on a drawable xml file?

`<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="Xamarin.Forms.Color.Red.ToAndroid" />`

I want to be able to have a list of colors on my shared project and be able to use them on the XML files on android?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via code, you can use the `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ColorExtensions` to convert from a `Xamarin.Forms` color to an `Android.Graphics.Color`.

Within your `Xamarin.Android` project (custom Forms renderers, etc...):

```
Android.Graphics.Color aColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Blue.ToAndroid()
```

`Xamarin.Forms.Color` is based on W3C standards so you can use these as your Android color xml resource file to provide the same colors within your custom *AXML*-based drawables/layout/etc...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
 <color name="fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
 <color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>
 <color name="gray">#808080</color>
 <color name="olive">#808000</color>
 <color name="purple">#800080</color>
 <color name="maroon">#800000</color>
 <color name="aqua">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="lime">#00FF00</color>
 <color name="teal">#008080</color>
 <color name="green">#008000</color>
 <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
 <color name="navy">#000080</color>
 <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Note: It is not possible to use code based / dynamic variables within AXML files

Comment: What I asked was if it was possible to use `<color name="black">Xamarin.Forms.Color.Black</color>` or create a custom color that comes from my Portable project?

Comment: Forms *custom* colors to Android XML-based resources, No,. If you are doing this via code, then yes, use the ColorExtensions `ToAndroid` *AXML* based resources are statically defined, you can not include a dynamic value  .